# Filtrar filas de un dataframe cuyas columnas tengan distinto/igual valor en R

Tags: r

Tengo un data frame con una clasificación de tumores.

El programa que uso utiliza dos métodos de clasificación diferentes y en algunas muestras me aparece clasificados de forma diferente.

me gustaría hacer dos tablas una con los tumores cuya clasificacion es igual (aquellas lineas cuyo valores de todas sus columnas son iguales) y otro con los que no coincide (aquellos cuyo valor de sus columnas son diferentes)

He intentado usar subset junto a $ para indicar las columnas e igualar valores

```
subset(tabla_comp, tabla_comp$Rfcms.RF.nearestCMS == tabla_comp$Rfcms.RF.predictedCMS)
```

un ejemplo (aunque esto solo me tendría en cuenta las dos primeras columnas pero para que veais por que idea he ido tirando) pero no funciona me dice:

> Error in Ops.factor(tabla_comp$Rfcms.RF.nearestCMS, tabla_comp$Rfcms.RF.predictedCMS)

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Hola Carlos, bienvenido. Puedes explicar mejor lo de "pero no funciona" ? Te da fallos? o no es el resultado deseado?

Comment: Hola Lois6b gracias por contestar. Exactamente me dice: Error in Ops.factor(tabla_comp$Rfcms.RF.nearestCMS, tabla_comp$Rfcms.RF.predictedCMS) : 
  level sets of factors are different

Comment: añade ese error a tu pregunta. Recuerda, los comentarios no deben contener informacion necesaria para la resolucion de la pregunta. trátalos como si en cualquier momento pudieran desaparecer. Ah y mentras te contestan o preguntan (no conozco de [tag:r] ) pasate por el  [tour](http://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para aprender más del funcinoamiento del sitio

Comment: Vale. ¡Muchas gracias!

Answer (score 2):

Para lograr lo que deseas tienes varias opciones.

**Usando subset**

Al llamar `subset`, no es necesario que especifíques con el signo de dólar (`$`) la tabla y la columna que estás comparando. Los nombres que uses serán buscados dentro de la tabla que des como el argumento `x`.

Así, puedes hacer lo siguiente:

```
subset(x = tabla_comp, 
       subset = Rfcms.RF.nearestCMS == Rfcms.RF.predictedCMS &
                Rfcms.RF.predictedCMS == SScms.SSP.nearestCMS & 
                SScmp.SSP.nearestCMS == SScms.SSP.predictedCMS)
```

**Usando corchetes**

Lo anterior puede ser aplicado a notación con corchetes (`[]`)

```
tabla_comp[tabla_comp$Rfcms.RF.nearestCMS == tabla_comp$Rfcms.RF.predictedCMS &
           tabla_comp$Rfcms.RF.predictedCMS == tabla_comp$SScms.SSP.nearestCMS & 
           tabla_comp$SScmp.SSP.nearestCMS == tabla_comp$SScms.SSP.predictedCMS, ]
```

**Usando corchetes y funciones**

Los métodos anteriores tienen la desventaja de que requieren de escribir muchas veces valores con nombres largos y completo, lo cuál puede propiciar que se comentan errores "de dedo" y con ello no obtengamos el resultado esperado.

Además de que requiere ser reescrito en caso de que tengamos una tabla con nombres de columna diferentes o con más o menos columnas. Esto hace más que nuestro código sea más difícil de mantener.

Por lo tanto, es deseable emplear las capacidades de R. Combinamos la notación de corchetes con algunas funciones.

```
mi_df[which(apply(X = mi_df, MARGIN = 1, FUN = function(renglon) { length(unique(renglon)) } ) == 1), ]
```

Usamos `apply` con una función anómina.

Primero obtenemos todos los valores únicos que tiene cada renglón de nuestra tabla usando `unique` y una vez hecho esto, usamos `length` para contar cuántos valores únicos tiene cada renglón. Si el resultado de esto es el número 1, entonces todos los valores son iguales en todas las columnas.

Usamos `which` dentro de los corchetes para seleccionar sólo los renglones donde sea Verdadero (`TRUE`) que el resultado de llamar esta función es `== 1`.

Este procedimiento se puede reusar sin importar qué tan "alta" o "ancha" sea la tabla en cuestión, siempre que tenga el mismo tipo de dato que la tabla que has mostrado en esta pregunta.

Answer (score 1):

Si querés usar el paquete `dplyr` (yo siempre lo prefiero!), podés hacer lo que sigue.

Primero genero un ejemplo de tu `dataframe`:

```
Rfcms.RF.nearestCMS   <- c("CMS1", "CMS2", "CMS1", "CMS2")
Rfcms.RF.predictedCMS <- c("CMS1", "CMS2", "CMS1", "CMS1")
SScms.SSP.nearestCMS  <- c("CMS1", "CMS2", "CMS2", "CMS1")

library(dplyr) 
(tabla_comp <- data_frame(Rfcms.RF.nearestCMS, 
                          Rfcms.RF.predictedCMS, 
                          SScms.SSP.nearestCMS)

# A tibble: 4 × 3
  Rfcms.RF.nearestCMS Rfcms.RF.predictedCMS SScms.SSP.nearestCMS
            <chr>                 <chr>                <chr>
1                CMS1                  CMS1                 CMS1
2                CMS2                  CMS2                 CMS2
3                CMS1                  CMS1                 CMS2
4                CMS2                  CMS1                 CMS1
```

Ahora genero la expresión que se va a evaluar en el paso siguiente, usando el `lazyeval::interp` (podés encontrar [más información acá](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/lazyeval/vignettes/lazyeval-old.html)). Acá es donde se comparan los valores de las columnas.

```
expr_iguales <- lazyeval::interp(quote(x == y & x == z), 
                                 x = as.name(names(tabla_comp)[1]), 
                                 y = as.name(names(tabla_comp)[2]),
                                 z = as.name(names(tabla_comp)[3]))
```

Ahora genero un dataframe con las filas que tienen iguales valores en todas las columnas usando `dplyr::filter`.

```
(iguales <- tabla_comp %>% filter(expr_iguales))

# A tibble: 2 × 3
  Rfcms.RF.nearestCMS Rfcms.RF.predictedCMS SScms.SSP.nearestCMS
                <chr>                 <chr>                <chr>
1                CMS1                  CMS1                 CMS1
2                CMS2                  CMS2                 CMS2
```

Después hago un `dplyr::anti_join` para generar el otro `dataframe` que tiene las filas cuyas columnas no son todas iguales.

```
(distintos <- anti_join(tabla_comp, iguales))

Joining, by = c("Rfcms.RF.nearestCMS", "Rfcms.RF.predictedCMS", "SScms.SSP.nearestCMS")
# A tibble: 2 × 3
  Rfcms.RF.nearestCMS Rfcms.RF.predictedCMS SScms.SSP.nearestCMS
                <chr>                 <chr>                <chr>
1                CMS2                  CMS1                 CMS1
2                CMS1                  CMS1                 CMS2
```

Como no especifico según qué columna quiero hacer el `anti_join`, lo hace según todas.